# Beautiful Soup not finding specific table by ID

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to parse a basketball reference player page to extract one of the tables from the page and work with the data from it. For some reason, though, beautiful soup cannot find the table in the page. I have tried to search for other tables in the page and it has successfully found them but for some reason will not find this specific one.

I have the following line which takes a link to the page of the specific player I am searching for and gets the BeautifulSoup version of it:

```
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(bball_ref_page.content, 'lxml')
```

I then search for the table with the following line:

```
table = page_soup.find('table', attrs={'id': 'per_poss'})
```

Whenever I try to `print(table)` it just comes out as None.
I have also tried searching for the contents by doing:

```
table = page_soup.find(attrs={'id': 'per_poss'})
```

same result of None

I have also tried searching for all tables in the `page_soup` and it returns a list of a bunch of tables not including the one I am looking for

I have tried changing the parse in the `page_soup` assignment to `html.parser` and the result remains the same. I have also tried printing the contents of `page_soup` and can find the table in their:

```
<div class="table_container current" id="div_per_poss">
        
        <table class="stats_table sortable row_summable" id="per_poss" data-cols-to-freeze="1,3"> <caption>Per 100 Poss Table</caption> <colgroup><col>....
```

Any ideas what might be causing this to happen?

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: @AndrejKesely here is an example of one https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jordami01.html

Answer (score 1):

The page is storing the `<table>` data inside the HTML comment `<!-- -->` so normally BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. To load it as pandas dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jordami01.html"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")
soup = BeautifulSoup("\n".join(soup.find_all(text=Comment)), "lxml")

df = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one("table#per_poss")))[0]
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Prints:

|  | Season | Age | Tm | Lg | Pos | G | GS | MP | FG | FGA | FG% | 3P | 3PA | 3P% | 2P | 2PA | 2P% | FT | FTA | FT% | ORB | DRB | TRB | AST | STL | BLK | TOV | PF | PTS | Unnamed: 29 | ORtg | DRtg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1984-85 | 21 | CHI | NBA | SG | 82 | 82 | 3144 | 12.9 | 25 | 0.515 | 0.1 | 0.8 | 0.173 | 12.7 | 24.2 | 0.526 | 9.7 | 11.5 | 0.845 | 2.6 | 5.6 | 8.2 | 7.4 | 3 | 1.1 | 4.5 | 4.4 | 35.5 | nan | 118 | 107 |
| 1 | 1985-86 | 22 | CHI | NBA | SG | 18 | 7 | 451 | 16 | 35 | 0.457 | 0.3 | 1.9 | 0.167 | 15.7 | 33.1 | 0.474 | 11.2 | 13.3 | 0.84 | 2.5 | 4.4 | 6.8 | 5.7 | 3.9 | 2.2 | 4.8 | 4.9 | 43.5 | nan | 109 | 107 |
| 2 | 1986-87 | 23 | CHI | NBA | SG | 82 | 82 | 3281 | 16.8 | 34.8 | 0.482 | 0.2 | 1 | 0.182 | 16.6 | 33.8 | 0.491 | 12.7 | 14.8 | 0.857 | 2.5 | 4 | 6.6 | 5.8 | 3.6 | 1.9 | 4.2 | 3.6 | 46.4 | nan | 117 | 104 |
| 3 | 1987-88 | 24 | CHI | NBA | SG | 82 | 82 | 3311 | 16.2 | 30.3 | 0.535 | 0.1 | 0.8 | 0.132 | 16.1 | 29.5 | 0.546 | 11 | 13.1 | 0.841 | 2.1 | 4.7 | 6.8 | 7.4 | 3.9 | 2 | 3.8 | 4.1 | 43.6 | nan | 123 | 101 |
| 4 | 1988-89 | 25 | CHI | NBA | SG | 81 | 81 | 3255 | 14.7 | 27.3 | 0.538 | 0.4 | 1.5 | 0.276 | 14.3 | 25.8 | 0.553 | 10.2 | 12.1 | 0.85 | 2.3 | 7.6 | 9.9 | 9.9 | 3.6 | 1 | 4.4 | 3.8 | 40 | nan | 123 | 103 |
| 5 | 1989-90 | 26 | CHI | NBA | SG | 82 | 82 | 3197 | 16 | 30.5 | 0.526 | 1.4 | 3.8 | 0.376 | 14.6 | 26.7 | 0.548 | 9.2 | 10.8 | 0.848 | 2.2 | 6.6 | 8.8 | 8.1 | 3.5 | 0.8 | 3.8 | 3.7 | 42.7 | nan | 123 | 106 |
| 6 | 1990-91 | 27 | CHI | NBA | SG | 82 | 82 | 3034 | 16.4 | 30.4 | 0.539 | 0.5 | 1.5 | 0.312 | 15.9 | 28.9 | 0.551 | 9.4 | 11.1 | 0.851 | 2 | 6.2 | 8.1 | 7.5 | 3.7 | 1.4 | 3.3 | 3.8 | 42.7 | nan | 125 | 102 |
| 7 | 1991-92 | 28 | CHI | NBA | SG | 80 | 80 | 3102 | 15.5 | 29.8 | 0.519 | 0.4 | 1.6 | 0.27 | 15 | 28.2 | 0.533 | 8 | 9.7 | 0.832 | 1.5 | 6.9 | 8.4 | 8 | 3 | 1.2 | 3.3 | 3.3 | 39.4 | nan | 121 | 102 |
| 8 | 1992-93 | 29 | CHI | NBA | SG | 78 | 78 | 3067 | 16.8 | 33.9 | 0.495 | 1.4 | 3.9 | 0.352 | 15.4 | 30 | 0.514 | 8.1 | 9.6 | 0.837 | 2.3 | 6.5 | 8.8 | 7.2 | 3.7 | 1 | 3.5 | 3.2 | 43 | nan | 119 | 102 |
| 9 | 1994-95 | 31 | CHI | NBA | SG | 17 | 17 | 668 | 13 | 31.5 | 0.411 | 1.2 | 2.5 | 0.5 | 11.7 | 29 | 0.403 | 8.5 | 10.6 | 0.801 | 2 | 7.2 | 9.1 | 7 | 2.3 | 1 | 2.7 | 3.7 | 35.7 | nan | 109 | 103 |
| 10 | 1995-96 | 32 | CHI | NBA | SG | 82 | 82 | 3090 | 15.6 | 31.5 | 0.495 | 1.9 | 4.4 | 0.427 | 13.7 | 27.1 | 0.506 | 9.3 | 11.2 | 0.834 | 2.5 | 6.7 | 9.3 | 6 | 3.1 | 0.7 | 3.4 | 3.3 | 42.5 | nan | 124 | 100 |
| 11 | 1996-97 | 33 | CHI | NBA | SG | 82 | 82 | 3106 | 15.8 | 32.5 | 0.486 | 1.9 | 5.1 | 0.374 | 13.9 | 27.4 | 0.507 | 8.2 | 9.9 | 0.833 | 1.9 | 6.3 | 8.3 | 6 | 2.4 | 0.8 | 2.9 | 2.7 | 41.8 | nan | 121 | 102 |
| 12 | 1997-98 | 34 | CHI | NBA | SG | 82 | 82 | 3181 | 14.9 | 32.1 | 0.465 | 0.5 | 2.1 | 0.238 | 14.4 | 30 | 0.482 | 9.6 | 12.2 | 0.784 | 2.2 | 5.8 | 8.1 | 4.8 | 2.4 | 0.8 | 3.1 | 2.6 | 40 | nan | 114 | 100 |
| 13 | 2001-02 | 38 | WAS | NBA | SF | 60 | 53 | 2093 | 14.3 | 34.4 | 0.416 | 0.3 | 1.4 | 0.189 | 14 | 33 | 0.426 | 6.8 | 8.6 | 0.79 | 1.3 | 7.5 | 8.8 | 8 | 2.2 | 0.7 | 4.2 | 3.1 | 35.7 | nan | 99 | 105 |
| 14 | 2002-03 | 39 | WAS | NBA | SF | 82 | 67 | 3031 | 12.2 | 27.4 | 0.445 | 0.3 | 1 | 0.291 | 11.9 | 26.4 | 0.45 | 4.8 | 5.8 | 0.821 | 1.3 | 7.7 | 8.9 | 5.6 | 2.2 | 0.7 | 3.1 | 3.1 | 29.5 | nan | 101 | 103 |
| 15 | Career | nan | nan | NBA | nan | 1072 | 1039 | 41011 | 15.3 | 30.7 | 0.497 | 0.7 | 2.2 | 0.327 | 14.5 | 28.5 | 0.51 | 9.2 | 11 | 0.835 | 2.1 | 6.3 | 8.3 | 7 | 3.1 | 1.1 | 3.7 | 3.5 | 40.4 | nan | 118 | 103 |
| 16 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 17 | 13 seasons | nan | CHI | NBA | nan | 930 | 919 | 35887 | 15.5 | 30.8 | 0.505 | 0.8 | 2.4 | 0.332 | 14.8 | 28.4 | 0.52 | 9.6 | 11.5 | 0.838 | 2.2 | 6.1 | 8.3 | 7.1 | 3.3 | 1.2 | 3.7 | 3.5 | 41.5 | nan | 120 | 103 |
| 18 | 2 seasons | nan | WAS | NBA | nan | 142 | 120 | 5124 | 13.1 | 30.3 | 0.431 | 0.3 | 1.1 | 0.241 | 12.8 | 29.1 | 0.439 | 5.6 | 7 | 0.805 | 1.3 | 7.6 | 8.9 | 6.6 | 2.2 | 0.7 | 3.6 | 3.1 | 32 | nan | 100 | 104 |

---

To iterate the rows of dataframe, you can use `df.iterrows()` for example:

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row["Season"], row["Age"])
```

Prints:

```
1984-85 21.0
1985-86 22.0
1986-87 23.0
1987-88 24.0
1988-89 25.0

...
```

Comment: how would you go about iterating through the table data in this instance?

Comment: @ParkerHarrelson1000 See my edit.

Comment: Gotcha thank you. Another problem though is this: some players do not have the table on their page at all because they did not play at a time when those metrics existed. So whenever I try `table = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one("table#" + table_id)))[0]` on a page that does not have that table it raises an exception and crashes the method. Is there a way to check that the table exists first?

Comment: @ParkerHarrelson1000 You could use `try: except:` to catch the exception and handle accordingly.